# Using dcast to reshape a data frame

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, dcast

I am having trouble understanding how I can use dcast (or any other function) to restructure my data frame.

I was given a data frame that looks something like this:

| Patient | DOB | Gender | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2-12-19 | F | Age | 25 |
| 1235 | 2-13-19 | M | Age | 25 |
| 1236 | 2-14-19 | F | BMI | 25 |
| 1237 | 2-15-19 | M | Age | 25 |
| 1238 | 2-16-19 | F | Height | 55 |
| 1239 | 2-17-19 | F | Age | 25 |

I want to be able to produce a data frame where each of the variables in the variable column are there own columns with their respective values.

I am having trouble understanding how dcast can be used when there are multiple different variables in one column to sort.

I want my final data frame to look something like this:

| Patient | DOB | Gender | Age | BMI | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2-12-19 | F | 25 | 25 | 55 |
| 1235 | 2-13-19 | M | 25 | 14 | 34 |
| 1236 | 2-14-19 | F | 25 | 30 | 20 |
| 1237 | 2-15-19 | M | 25 | 45 | 25 |
| 1238 | 2-16-19 | F | 55 | 25 | 13 |
| 1239 | 2-17-19 | F | 25 | 56 | 40 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code to spread out the variables in `variable` column:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Patient DOB     Gender   Age   BMI Height
    <int> <chr>   <chr>  <int> <int>  <int>
1    1234 2-12-19 F         25    NA     NA
2    1235 2-13-19 M         25    NA     NA
3    1236 2-14-19 F         NA    25     NA
4    1237 2-15-19 M         25    NA     NA
5    1238 2-16-19 F         NA    NA     55
6    1239 2-17-19 F         25    NA     NA
```